# php dom get image src path encode

Tags: php

I use below codes to extract image src path .but this is a problem when the image filename has  special character(eg:~ DQBTZ_UC(G@STWO_1R2U_Q4.gif),the output turn to be like this :~  6Z6W4%255BO29FQ%255BA4YN_%255BFR9%2529M.gif

How to fix this issue? sorry for my poor English.

```
function _get_imagepath($content){

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($content);
    $imagepaths=array();
    $imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    $folder=file_directory_path();
    foreach($imageTags as $tag) {

        $imagepaths[]=$tag->getAttribute('src');
    }

    if(!empty($imagepaths)){

        return $imagepaths;
    }else{

        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

Comment: hmm, I dont see an issue here, you find your src, and save it somewhere or use it somehow... pls explain what do you expect it to do

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems your filenames are URL encoded. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

i.e:

```
foreach($imageTags as $tag) {
    $imagepaths[]=urldecode($tag->getAttribute('src'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the encoded URL.

You want to use `urldecode`:

> Decodes any %## encoding in the given string. Plus symbols ('+') are
>   decoded to a space character.

[urldecode() in PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
return $imagepaths;
```

with

```
return urldecode($imagepaths);
```

to decode your image url.